# using dictionary in python for parsing trace files

Tags: python, arrays, file, parsing, dictionary

I am going to parse a trace file using python. I read every line of my file and I want to add the line to a dictionary. After I separate each line with space keyword and add each line's columns to my dictionary, I print the result. But the problem is that my values are not in a order as what they are in my trace file.

In another word, assume that the firs line of my trace file is as follow:

- 0.1 1 2 cbr 1000 ------- 2 1.0 2.0 0 0

My codes are as follows:

```
global dics
dics = []
count = 0
line_dic = {}
with codecs.open("trace.tr", "r", "UTF8") as inputFile:
    inputFile=inputFile.readlines()
for line in inputFile:
    item = []
    item = line.split(" ");
    line_dic['event'] = item[0]
    line_dic['time'] = item[1]
    line_dic['from_node'] = item[2]
    line_dic['to_node'] = item[3]
    line_dic['pkt_type'] = item[4]
    line_dic['pkt_size'] = item[5]
    line_dic['flags'] = item[6]
    line_dic['fid'] = item[7]
    line_dic['srcadd'] = item[8]
    line_dic['dstadd'] = item[9]
    line_dic['seqnum'] = item[10]
    line_dic['pkti'] = item[11]

    dics.append(line_dic)
    print dics
```

the result of print command is

```
[{'pkt_type': u'cbr', 'pkti': u'0\n', 'pkt_size': u'1000', 'seqnum': u'0', 'event': u'+', 'srcadd': u'1.0', 'flags': u'-------', 'fid': u'2', 'time': u'0.1', 'dstadd': u'2.0', 'to_node': u'2', 'from_node': u'1'}]
```

As you can see, the first item must be event, based on my knowledge. But this is `'pkt_type': u'cbr'`!

I don't know what is the problem?

Comment: there is no problem ... a `dict` has no order, there is no such a thing as a first item in your `dict`

Comment: @gommb Thank you. When I am trying to use OrderDict ,  I can not use dics[counter]['event'].

Comment: @JulienSpronck, Thank you. I need to have access my values such as dics[3]['event']. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: when you try to access `dics[3]['event']` what error do you get?

Comment: I got KeyError 0. But I used Julien codes and every thing is ok. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see in your code is that `line_dic` should be initialized for every line (I moved `line_dic = {}` inside the for loop). Without that, you will overwrite dictionaries of previous lines.

```
dics = []
count = 0

with codecs.open("trace.tr", "r", "UTF8") as inputFile:
    inputFile=inputFile.readlines()
for line in inputFile:
    item = line.split(" ");

    line_dic = {}

    line_dic['event'] = item[0]
    line_dic['time'] = item[1]
    line_dic['from_node'] = item[2]
    line_dic['to_node'] = item[3]
    line_dic['pkt_type'] = item[4]
    line_dic['pkt_size'] = item[5]
    line_dic['flags'] = item[6]
    line_dic['fid'] = item[7]
    line_dic['srcadd'] = item[8]
    line_dic['dstadd'] = item[9]
    line_dic['seqnum'] = item[10]
    line_dic['pkti'] = item[11]

    dics.append(line_dic)
print dics
```

Then, there should be no problem calling `dics[3]['event']`. Your dict does not need to be sorted in order to make that call.